# How to properly iterate through a big json file

Tags: php, arrays, json, mongodb, iterator

I have a 34 GB json file that has many data inside. I tried to import into my mongodb by using mongoimport --file file.json - but it failed ofcourse the file is too big and threw a memory system throw error you know it. Is it possible to use php code to iterate through the file with a cursor? I want to know how the file is build, but I do not know how to view an example array of it. From the source I could get an example array:

```
{
     "_id": ObjectId("53b29644aafd413977b23b7e"),
     "summonerId": NumberLong(24570940),
     "region": "euw",
     "updatedAt": NumberLong(1404212804),
     "season": NumberLong(4),
     "stats": {
         "110": {
             "totalSessionsPlayed": NumberLong(3),
             "totalSessionsLost": NumberLong(2),
             "totalSessionsWon": NumberLong(1),
             "totalChampionKills": NumberLong(34),
             "totalDamageDealt": NumberLong(415051),
             "totalDamageTaken": NumberLong(63237),
             "mostChampionKillsPerSession": NumberLong(12),
             "totalMinionKills": NumberLong(538),
             "totalDoubleKills": NumberLong(5),
             "totalTripleKills": NumberLong(1),
             "totalDeathsPerSession": NumberLong(18),
             "totalGoldEarned": NumberLong(40977),
             "totalTurretsKilled": NumberLong(6),
             "totalPhysicalDamageDealt": NumberLong(381668),
             "totalMagicDamageDealt": NumberLong(31340),
             "totalAssists": NumberLong(25),
             "maxChampionsKilled": NumberLong(12),
             "maxNumDeaths": NumberLong(10)
         }
     }
 }
```

The field stats contains more arrays, 110 is just an example.
How can I iterate through this big sized file or how can I import it into my mongodb?
For example; I want to echo summonerid,championid (which is 110 in this case),totalSessionsPlayed.
It has to reloop as much as it needs until theres no championid left for this particular summonerid.

Again... A summonerID has a list of champions that it has been playing in his playing career. Champions are referring to (in this example) 110. Every single summonerid can contain multiple champions and I want to have all champions, how many times the champion has been played (totalsessionplayed) by summonerid.

Comment: Consider exactly how much memory your PHP would need to load and parse this file (at least double the size of the file), then ask yourself if you can make that much memory available to PHP

Comment: the file is 34gb... php can never parse it at once i think

Comment: did you check the net??  check php-streaming-json-parser   -- https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser

Comment: I did check but thats chinese for me. Even after trying to evaluate the examples given, i have no clue how to use it :x

Comment: Little late but this is also a convenient solution: https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine

Answer (score 17):

You'll want to use a streaming parser. These only pull small portions of your file into memory at a time.

They come in a couple different flavors: SAX-like push parsers, and pull parsers. [*XML reader models: SAX versus XML pull parser*](http://www.firstobject.com/xml-reader-sax-vs-xml-pull-parser.htm) gives an overview of the difference.

---

### Push Parser

This is a quick example using [salsify/json-streaming-parser](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser).

As it rolls through the file we'll keep track of the `summonerId`, `championId`, and state. It's all event-based - you don't get random access with a sequential parser so you have to keep track of things yourself. Every time a `totalSessionsPlayed` comes up it'll echo out the *summonerId*, *championId*, and *totalSessionsPlayed*.

---

#### data.json

This is a paired-down json file for demonstration purposes.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "53b29644aafd413977b23b7e",
        "summonerId": 24570940,
        "region": "euw",
        "stats": {
            "110": {
                "totalSessionsPlayed": 3,
                "totalSessionsLost": 2,
                "totalSessionsWon": 1
            },
            "112": {
                "totalSessionsPlayed": 45,
                "totalSessionsLost": 2,
                "totalSessionsWon": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "asdfasdfasdf",
        "summonerId": 555555,
        "region": "euw",
        "stats": {
            "42": {
                "totalSessionsPlayed": 65,
                "totalSessionsLost": 2,
                "totalSessionsWon": 1
            },
            "88": {
                "totalSessionsPlayed": 99,
                "totalSessionsLost": 2,
                "totalSessionsWon": 1
            }
        }
    }
]
```

#### Example:

```
class ListMatchUps extends JsonStreamingParser\Listener\IdleListener
{

    private $key;
    private $summonerId;
    private $championId;
    private $inStats;

    public function start_document()
    {
        $this->key        = null;
        $this->summonerId = null;
        $this->championId = null;
        $this->inStats    = false;
    }

    public function start_object()
    {
        if ($this->key === 'stats') {
            $this->inStats = true;
        } else if ($this->inStats) {
            $this->championId = $this->key;
        }
    }

    public function end_object()
    {
        if ($this->championId !== null) {
            $this->championId = null;
        } else if ($this->inStats) {
            $this->inStats = false;
        } else {
            $this->summonerId = null;
        }
    }

    public function key($key)
    {
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    public function value($value)
    {
        switch ($this->key) {
            case 'summonerId':
                $this->summonerId = $value;
                break;
            case 'totalSessionsPlayed':
                echo "{$this->summonerId},{$this->championId},$value\n";
                break;
        }
    }
}

$stream = fopen('data.json', 'r');
$listener = new ListMatchUps();
try {
    $parser = new JsonStreamingParser_Parser($stream, $listener);
    $parser->parse();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    fclose($stream);
    throw $e;
}
```

#### Output:

```
24570940,110,3
24570940,112,45
555555,42,65
555555,88,99
```

---

### Pull Parser

This is using a parser I recently wrote, [pcrov/jsonreader](https://github.com/pcrov/JsonReader) (requires PHP 7.)

Same data.json as above.

#### Example:

```
use pcrov\JsonReader\JsonReader;

$reader = new JsonReader();
$reader->open("data.json");

while($reader->read("summonerId")) {
    $summonerId = $reader->value();
    $reader->next("stats");
    foreach($reader->value() as $championId => $stats) {
        echo "$summonerId, $championId, {$stats['totalSessionsPlayed']}\n";
    }
}
$reader->close();
```

#### Output:

```
24570940, 110, 3
24570940, 112, 45
555555, 42, 65
555555, 88, 99
```

Comment: This is perfect. Do you have any idea how we can tell the parser to stop early when it's done with a certain array/object or a certain key name?  The issue with the current implementation is that it seems to scan the entire json file before it stops.  I tried calling end_document in the listener to stop, but the script just continues to parse.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a stream parsing. There are several libraries that can help you with it.
For example, I tried [JSON Machine](https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine) (it's mentioned in [Awesome PHP](https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php) project repository) and it works fine for me:

```
use \JsonMachine\Items;

$fruits = Items::fromFile('1.json', ['pointer' => '/stats']);
foreach ($fruits as $name => $data) {
        echo $name . " totalSessionsPlayed: " . $data->totalSessionsPlayed . "\n";
}
```

Another example similar library [JSON Stream Parser](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser), but I haven't tried parse your JSON example with it.

Comment: correct and definitive answer in 2023+! Works through 100k complex JSON objects with millions of lines in **a minute**, using **less than 1 megabyte**. Chad developers.

Answer (score -1):

Handling a large JSON file with a size of 34 GB in memory can be challenging, and it's a good idea to process it in smaller chunks to avoid memory-related issues. Here's an approach using PHP to iterate through the large JSON file and import the data into MongoDB in smaller batches.

1. **Split the Large JSON File**: To avoid loading the entire JSON file into memory, you can split it into smaller chunks using a command like `split` (on Unix-based systems) or a custom script.

   Example using `split`:

   ```bash
   split -l 10000 large_file.json split_
   ```

   This command splits the JSON file into smaller files with 10,000 lines each.
2. **PHP Script to Import into MongoDB**: Write a PHP script to iterate through the smaller JSON files and insert the data into MongoDB in batches. You can use the `MongoDB` PHP extension for MongoDB interactions.

   Here's a simplified example:

   ```php
   <?php
   // Load the MongoDB extension
   $mongo = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

   // Iterate through the split JSON files
   $fileList = glob("split_*");

   foreach ($fileList as $file) {
       $lines = file($file);
       foreach ($lines as $line) {
           // Parse each line as JSON
           $document = json_decode($line, true);

           // Insert the document into MongoDB
           $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
           $bulk->insert($document);

           // Execute the bulk write
           $mongo->executeBulkWrite('your_database.your_collection', $bulk);
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```

   Make sure to replace `'mongodb://localhost:27017'`, `'your_database'`, and `'your_collection'` with your MongoDB connection details and target database and collection names.
3. **Processing the Data**: Once you've imported the data into MongoDB, you can use MongoDB queries to process and retrieve the specific data you need. For example, you can use aggregation queries to group the data by `summonerId`, `championId`, and calculate `totalSessionsPlayed`.

Please note that this is a simplified example, and you may need to adapt it to your specific requirements and ensure it handles potential errors and exceptions during the import process. Additionally, MongoDB might have specific optimizations and considerations for handling large datasets, so you should refer to MongoDB's documentation for further guidance on optimizing and querying large collections.